# Stream zipped file to client side in Node.js and Express without writing to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js API running express which receives a zipped file from an s3 bucket. I wish to send the file directly to the client-side without having to unzip or write the file to disk. The client script will unpack the zip file in this setup.

How can you send a response with a zip file or buffer to then be unzipped by the client-side.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should work? Just stream the file to res:

```js
setResponseHeader('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.zip');
setResponseHeader('Content-Type: application/zip');

s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

Comment: Does this method assume the user will download the myfile.zip or can the zip file then be unzipped by the application layer?